# Concatenate Strings in C - `strcpy(s1 += strlen(s1), s2)`

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I am trying to understand a method to concatenate strings as proposed in "The Standard C Library".

After discussing how to concatenate two strings, s1 and s2. The author proposes that for multiple strings (more than 2),

> "...favour a form such as `strcpy(s1 += strlen(s1), s2)`That saves repeated, and ever-lengthening, rescans of the initial part of the string..." (pg. 395)

I'm having trouble making sense of this code snippet. My understanding is that he's adding the length of `s1` to the pointer in order to pass the index of the Null character to strcpy, so that strcpy will not have to loop through s1 to find the Null character and can just start copying s2 into s1, is that correct?

If my understanding is correct, how does this cause any efficiency when in place of strcpy, strlen will still have to loop through the string to determine its length?

Comment: Because for multiple concatenations you don't have to scan the *whole* string that is being built. The downside is it is easier to lose track of whether there is enough space to call the inherently dangerous `strcat` or its equivalent.

Comment: `strcpy()` doesn't scan for the null terminator before copying.  `strcat()` does.  The author is avoiding `strcat(s1, s2)` by using `strcpy(s1 += strlen(s1), s2)` instead. But, `strlen()` scans for the null terminator, so this does not really gain anything. But, if you can avoid `strlen()`, then this becomes more useful

Comment: Message from the boss:https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: @Ry- It is a "solution" for the same "problem".

Comment: @wildplasser: Sorry, commented on the wrong question. :P

Comment: Note that some care is required to make sure you aren't running past the end of the target buffer — such care is always required in C.  The code fragment shown is the core of good way of doing it (it avoids the quadratic behaviour that repeated string concatenation with `strcat()` incurs — see Shlemiel the Painter; Google knows if you don't, and see the Joel on Software link above).  But it isn't "safe" unless there is knowledge of the bigger context in which it is being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: `s1 += strlen(s1)` is going to give you a pointer to the terminating 0, so `strcpy(..., s2)` is going to work like `strcat()` - appending `s2` to `s1` (assuming there is enough space in `s1`. Note that `strcpy()` doesn't "loop though s1 to find the Null" - it just writes at the location given `strcat` does find the Null though.

The key to the optimization is the `+=` we are actually changing `s1` (you better have taken a copy of the original value). So we only take the length of the last string added and not the length from the start of the first string (which is what a `strcat`solution would do).

Comment: "*Note that `strcpy()` doesn't "loop though s1 to find the Null"*" - true, but `strlen()` does, so `strcat(s1, s2)` and `strcpy(s1 += strlen(s1), s2)` are effectively the same in terms of performance. Both scan `s1` to determine where to append `s2`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yep - just addressing the line in the question where OP implies (by my reading) that strcpy "looks for Null"

Comment: @RemyLebeau But now `s1` points to the end of the (original) string, rather than the start of it, so a subsequent call will only have to iterate to the end of the newly concatenated portion.  It is not as efficient as it could be, but it is an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The `strcpy(s1 + strlen(s1),s2)` *does* limit the amount of rescan of `s1` with repeated calculations to the additional length of a given `s2` on the next round.

But, IMO, instead of this *trick*, it's better to just write a function that doesn't require *any* rescan:

```
char *
xstrcat(char *s1,const char *s2)
{

    for (;  *s1 != 0;  ++s1);

    for (;  *s2 != 0;  ++s1, ++s2)
        *s1 = *s2;
    *s1 = 0;

    return s1;
}

void
func(char *s1,const char *s2,const char *s3,const char *s4)
{

    s1 = xstrcat(s1,s2);
    s1 = xstrcat(s1,s3);
    s1 = xstrcat(s1,s4);
}
```

Comment: The idea is the `s1 += strlen(s1)` also retains some memory of the `strlen` operation (in `s1`) reducing the cost for subsequent operations.  It's not perfect, but it does prevent the traversal amount from compounding on each successive concatenation.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Okay, doing the `strlen` notion, is [somewhat] better [I've edited my answer]. But, this is the first time I've ever seen it (either in description or working code), so if it were worth the complexity, IMO, it would be in more widespread usage.